# SonarQube showing error when exception is there

Tags: java, sonarqube

for the below code Sonarqube is showing error , saying "Either log or rethrow this exception." fof the catch block , how can we handle the same

```
  private ResponseEntity<String> getResponse(String url,
                                                      String logName,
                                                      HttpMethod httpMethod,
                                                      HttpEntity<String> httpEntity,
                                                      HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest)
    {
        httpServletRequest.setAttribute("api", logName);
        ResponseEntity<String> checkEntity;
        try {
            if(logName.equals("Activate All Offer Api")){
                checkEntity = requestFactory.getRestTemplate().exchange(url, httpMethod, httpEntity, String.class);
            }else {
                checkEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, httpMethod, httpEntity, String.class);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new LocalHttpClientErrorException(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
        return checkEntity;
    }
```

Comment: It tells you to re-throw the exception properly and properly doesn't mean to cut the stacktrace of the original exception and just use the localized exception message.

Answer (score 0):

For the warning to go away you need to attach the original exception as a cause to the LocalHttpClientErrorException either in a constructor parameter or if that is not possible, using the initCause(Throwable) method. But there are a few other problems there too.

1. You're catching generic Exception. This is always a sign of serious code smell.
2. You're passing a localized message to LocalHttpClientErrorException. Localization should be a responsibility of the UI layer, never the business logic.

Comment: I would soften "always a sign" to "typically", "often" etc. Sometimes you do need to catch Exception, e.g. you invoke a Callable's call method in the try.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's fair.